# Trouble with installing Bower

Tags: bower

I am trying to install Bower. Need Bower to install zurb Foundation. I am a newbie in this, a UX designer learning the frontend.

```
    npm install - g bower
npm ERR! Error: not_found document not found: -
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:308:14)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.6.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-" "g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/anandka
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anandka/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you must remove the space before the *g* option. 
npm is not finding package **-**, so:

```
npm install -g bower
```